# Breadcrumb PrimeNg no se encuentra

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs, primeng

estoy intentando usar Breadcrumb de PrimeNG en su version 15 y me da este error

Error: src/app/modules/Dashboard/Pages/index/index.component.html:2:29 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'model' since it isn't a known property of 'p-breadcrumb'.

1. If 'p-breadcrumb' is an Angular component and it has 'model' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-breadcrumb' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

Asi esta el componente donde quiero implementarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y estos son los modulos que se relacionan

DashboardModule maneja todo lo que tiene que ver con el dashboard

PrimeNgModule maneja todos los componentes de PrimeNg

AppModule principal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]